# Cannot connect to mongoDB container using default docker network

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` files:

docker-compose.base.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:jessie
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    volumes:
      - /home/marcoskichel/Documents/databases/mongoDB:/data

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express:0.44
    ports:
      - "9001:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="mongodb"
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME="admin"
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD="admin"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  api:
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

  services:

    api:
      build: .
      environment:
        - "JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8090"
```

I am running containers with the following command:

`sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml up --abort-on-container-exit`

My problem is that `api` and `mongo-express` containers cannot connect to `mongodb`.

This is the full log i get from docker:

```
Attaching to condohubsubscriptions_mongodb_1, api, mongo-express
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=c67635e957ff
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true }, storage: { mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:53.851+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3424M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.014+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518973074:14590][1:0x7f8e651a8a00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 7/4736
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.133+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518973074:133499][1:0x7f8e651a8a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 8
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.246+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1518973074:246846][1:0x7f8e651a8a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 8 through 8
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.424+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected configuration for non-active storage engine mmapv1 when current storage engine is wiredTiger
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.439+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongodb_1        | 2018-02-18T16:57:54.439+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
mongo-express    | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express    | ------------------------
mongo-express    | 
mongo-express    | 
mongo-express    | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
mongo-express    | Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
api              | 
api              |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
api              |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
api              | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
api              |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
api              |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
api              |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
api              |  :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)
api              | 
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:55.804  INFO 6 --- [           main] b.c.c.s.SubscriptionsApplication         : Starting SubscriptionsApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on eff77776b4d4 with PID 6 (/condohub-subscriptions.jar started by root in /)
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:55.809  INFO 6 --- [           main] b.c.c.s.SubscriptionsApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:55.942  INFO 6 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2cdf8d8a: startup date [Sun Feb 18 16:57:55 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:57.541  INFO 6 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8fa3e2cb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
mongo-express    | 
mongo-express    | /node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265
mongo-express    |         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
mongo-express    |                                       ^
mongo-express    | MongoError: failed to connect to server ["mongodb":27017] on first connect
mongo-express    |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:326:35)
mongo-express    |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
mongo-express    |     at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
mongo-express    |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
mongo-express    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
mongo-express    |     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
mongo-express    |     at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
mongo-express    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:175:49)
mongo-express    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
mongo-express    |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:58.326  INFO 6 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:58.369  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:58.370  INFO 6 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:58.534  INFO 6 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
api              | 2018-02-18 16:57:58.535  INFO 6 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2598 ms
```

Comment: when you do `docker-compose up` it doesnt mean the mongodb is online immediately to start receiving commands, try to start mongodb first and then the rest. Also provide log for mongodb

Comment: Thanks @MazelTov for your help, if you look closely to my compose files, there is this  ``depends_on`` configuration parameter on all containers, but  `mongodb`. This is supposed to manage the containers start order. I am editing the question with more log.

Comment: i see `depends_on` but it doesnt know if mongo (the application inside docker container is really running), it just start it in order... and if your mongo express loads faster than the DB itself it might throw this error, https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Ok @MazelTov, I understand. I updated the question. Also noticed that ``mongodb`` is being called ``mongodb_1`` for some reason, maybe this is the problem right?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you use quotes in environment variables. In this case the yaml represent the value "mongodb" as ""mongodb"" which the express app cant access. So removing the "" will do the trick

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:0.44
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```